# How do I use a callback in a nested function in Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback, ffprobe

I'm receiving a "TypeError: callback is not a function" which leads me to believe I am misunderstanding how to use callbacks in a nested function.

Function:

```
function getAudioInfo(filePath, callback) {
  ffprobe(filePath, { path: ffprobeStatic.path }, function (err, info) {
    console.log("ffprobe output: " + JSON.stringify(info));
    if (err) {
      console.log("getAudioInfo error: " + err);
      callback(err, null);
    } else {
      callback(null, info);
    }
  });
}
```

Call:

```
   function checkAudioInfo(metadata_json, callback) {

      var filePath = metadata_json['current_path'];

      getAudioInfo(filePath, function(err, info) {
          if (err) {
            callback(err);
          }
          //operations on info
          callback(null, metadata_json);
      });//end getAudioInfo

    }//end checkAudioInfo
```

Is this an improper use of callbacks?

Edit:

Error was found in passing to the function wrapping checkAudioInfo (another callback error).  I will make edits and post the correct code shortly.  All your questions helped me figure out the answer.  Thanks!

Comment: In the second bit of code, where is `callback` defined? That's likely the problem. Where is the error pointing to?

Comment: Good call.  I forgot to include a function wrapping the second bit of code.  I'll make the edit now.  Apologies.

Comment: We need to see where `callback` is originating from, because whatever is being passed apparently isn't a function. Where is `checkAudioInfo` getting `callback` from?

Comment: Can you specify which line is causing the error? There are two places that 'callback' is used which might be confusing.

Comment: I can't replicate the problem if I replace `ffprobe` with a proxy. I did get an error on `ffprobeStatic.path` being undefined, but after changing it to null, everything worked. So I don't think the problem is in the code shown. If you don't like working with node.js style callbacks, you can use `util.promifisy` to turn them into promises, making this entire chain way shorter.

Comment: Figured out the error.  There was a problem with my wrapper function.  i will post the edited solution shortly once I clean things up.  Thanks for the help!  votes+ all around.  Yes, I will definitley give util.promisify for my next project.

Comment: If you don't intend to call callback twice in case of error (in the second block of code), you should return after calling the callback(err). e.g. if(err) { return callback(err); }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first block of code accepts a callback. The second argument should be a function. This function will be called when the asynchronous code is done.

Your second block of code calls the function in the first. The second argument you are passing is a function. So far, so good.

Inside that function, you try to call `callback`. This fails because there is no variable with that name in scope.

At this point, it is very unclear what you are trying to do. The function you are passing **is** the callback. You are supposed to use it to do *something useful* with the data it is passed by the code from the first code block.

Now, you *could* get a reference to the callback function by using a named function expression:

```
  getAudioInfo(filePath, function callback (err, info) {
      if (err) {
        callback(err);
      }
      //operations on info
      callback(null, metadata_json);
  });//end getAudioInfo
```

… but then you are just calling it recursively and infinitely, which is not useful.

---

re Edit:

You have now added a *second* variable called `callback`:

```
function checkAudioInfo(metadata_json, callback) {
```

This makes more sense.

If **that** `callback` is undefined, then that is because you aren't passing it a value when you **call** `checkAudioInfo`. You haven't included that code.

Comment: Your line of questioning made me realize I was incorrectly passing on my call to checkAudioInfo.  Thanks for the help!  I will post the solution shortly.

Answer (score 0):

The function itself `function(err, info)` is the callback which is called inside of `getAudioInfo`!

What is `metadata_json`? Do you mean `info`?

Comment: @indigo Do you changed your issue description? Now its looks differently!